# Setting objects in an ArrayList to null

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, null, garbage-collection

If I was to have an ArrayList of objects, and I set a few of them to null, are they susceptible to gc? Or will they stay since they are still being referenced by the ArrayList

ex:

```
for(NPC n : NPCs){
    n.act();
    n.draw(frame);
    if(n == outOfMap){
            n = null;
        }

}
```

If that loop is "always" being iterated over, will the outOfMap objects be collected? or simply stay there will a null value?

Comment: Anything which is reachable is not eligible for garbage collection. Since a reference still exists somewhere, they will remain in memory. You need to actually remove them from the ArrayList with `ArrayList.remove`.

Comment: I get a concurrentModificationException, How can i bypass that?

Comment: @ChrisHayes: You can also set the n-th element to `null` in the list.

Comment: @BenMarshall: Do you really have to do that within the loop? You can just throw away the list afterwards. If it is necessary to be so timely, you need to use Iterator#remove

Comment: It's not that I want to be extremely timely, it's that the list will always be there and be iterated over,so i can't just throw away the list. I just want to add and remove objects from it depending on their position, and since the remove method gives me a concurrentModifierException, I was seeing if setting them to null would do the job.

Comment: @Thilo: You can do that, but you also have to be wary, because 1) some list implementations can throw a `NullPointerException`, and 2) list implementations are not required to support the `set` method.

Comment: List implementation are not required to support `remove`, either ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish between objects and references to them. For the same one object, multiple references could point to it. When the number of references reaches 0, the object is a candidate to be removed by the garbage collector.

In this loop:

```
for(NFC n : NFCs)
{
   n = null;
}
```

The `n` reference is different than the reference the ArrayList uses to track the object in the list, so setting n to null reduces the references to the object down by one, but it leaves the reference from the ArrayList to the object intact and as such, the object is not a candidate for garbage collection. You should use the `remove` method to remove the object from the ArrayList. At that point, if no other references to the object exist elsewhere, it'll be a candidate for removal.

Comment: "so setting n to null reduces the references to the object down by one". Which would have happened anyway in the next line as the loop enters its next iteration (and `n` is set to the next element).

Answer (score 0):

You're confused I think between variables and objects. If a variable references null, there's nothing to GC since variables aren't GC'd, objects are. The ArrayList won't be GC'd if there's a valid reference to it, and if it contains nulls, then there's nothing in it to be held in memory or to GC.

If on the other hand, the ArrayList contains objects, and then later you null an item or two, then it's not the ArrayList that will determine the GC-ability of the object since its reference to it has been severed, but whether or not other objects reference them.